# Convert scientific notation to float in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an easy way to convert a number in scientific notation to float in BigQuery? 
For example:

```
8.32E-4 to 0,08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supposed this is for reporting purposes maybe? Does this solve for you?

```
SELECT FORMAT("%.10f", 8.32E-8) number UNION ALL
SELECT FORMAT("%.6f", 8.32E-4) UNION ALL
SELECT FORMAT("%4.f", 8.32E+4) UNION ALL
SELECT FORMAT("%10.f", 8.32E+8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but for anyone else looking for a solution, this query (although a little clunky) should work for all scientific notation fields.

The difficulty is that BigQuery will convert any numbers greater than E±3 to scientific notation. The workaround is to cast the number as a string. If you're using this output for reporting purposes, it shouldn't be a problem. If you need to work with the numbers, make sure you've completed all calculations before converting:

```
SELECT
number
,base_num
,exponent
,CASE WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'E([+-])') = '+'
      THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(STRING((base_num * (POW(10, exponent)))), r'(\d+\.0)')
      ELSE STRING(base_num * (POW(10, (exponent * -1))))
      END AS converted_number
FROM
   (SELECT
   number
   ,FLOAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'(.*)E')) base_num
   ,INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'E[+-](\d+)')) exponent
   FROM 
      (SELECT "8E+1" AS number)
      ,(SELECT "1.6E-3" AS number)
      ,(SELECT "8.32E-4" AS number)
      ,(SELECT "2.92E+9" AS number)
    )
```

**Explanation:**

`FLOAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'(.*)E'))` returns the number before the E (as a string) and then converts it to a float.

`INTEGER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'E[+-](\d+)'))` returns the number after the E (as a string) and then converts it to an integer.

Then, raise 10 to the exponent (or its inverse, if it's negative) and multiply this by the base number.

Finally, cast as a string to maintain non-scientific notation. For numbers greater than 1, "round" to a single 0 after the decimal using regex for easier reading.

**Output:**

```
Row   number      base_num    exponent    converted_number   
1     8E+1        8.0         1           80.0   
2     1.6E-3      1.6         3           0.001600   
3     8.32E-4     8.32        4           0.000832   
4     2.92E+9     2.92        9           2920000000.0
```